# Formatting a select list by its leading number with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a select box, see below. The output is from an address system we can't change. I want the formatting to be in numeric order, i.e. 1 Smith Road, 3 Smith Road, 5 Smith Road etc...

I've been using the following script to figure this out and I can see the parseInt is converting the string to a number, doing the correct ordering but removing the last part of the address. so I'm just getting 1, 2, 3 etc in the output.

```js
$(function() {
    var opAddress = [];
    $('option').each(function() {
      opAddress.push(parseInt($(this).text(), 10));
    });
    opAddress.sort(numOrdDesc);
    $('option').each(function() {
      $(this).text(opAddress.pop());
    });
  });

  function numOrdDesc(a, b) {
    return (b - a);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option>1 Smith Road</option>
    <option>10 Smith Road</option>
    <option>11 Smith Road</option>
    <option>12 Smith Road</option>
    <option>3 Smith Road</option>
    <option>5 Smith Road</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas, can anyone point me in the right direction of documentation etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this a little. You can call `sort()` on a jQuery object while providing the logic to sort by. As the text of each option begins with a number you can simply call `parseInt()` on it to get that numerical value to sort by without having to update the element's attributes. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var $select = $('select');
  var $option = $select.find('option').sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt($(a).text(), 10) - parseInt($(b).text(), 10);
  }).appendTo($select).first().prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1 Smith Road</option>
  <option>10 Smith Road</option>
  <option>11 Smith Road</option>
  <option>12 Smith Road</option>
  <option>3 Smith Road</option>
  <option>5 Smith Road</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you that's great. Only one small thing the 12 Smith Road is showing first in the dropdown now, I assume that's the ordering by default until I add ASC/DESC?

Comment: @ultrarun that's a side-effect of the sorting. I've updated the answer for you so that it sets the first `option` as selected again after sorting

Answer (score 1):

To get the new first option to be selected, change the code provided by @Rory McCrossan slightly to the following:

```js
$(function() {
  var $select = $('select');
  var $option = $select.find('option').sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt($(a).text(), 10) - parseInt($(b).text(), 10);
  }).appendTo($select);
  $("select")[0].options[0].selected = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option  >1 Smith Road</option>
  <option>10 Smith Road</option>
  <option >11 Smith Road</option>
  <option>12 Smith Road</option>
  <option>3 Smith Road</option>
  <option>5 Smith Road</option>
</select>
```